# Cocos2d change image of hero in accelerometer when an object hits it

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Hi. I am new on this website and also in cocos2d. I am a student and I need your help.

I am making a game based on one of the tutorials in a cocos2d game development book. The concept is simple; different objects are falling from the top of the screen and I have to avoid or catch them by tilting the device. The main character, which is one which has to avoid objects, has different properties which can change by grabbing different objects (e.g. the player may have a shield if it grabs one). In order to display the shield I have to change the sprite of the player. I am not sure how I can achieve this. Could anyone help me in providing some guidelines on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setTexture to switch the image (texture) of your current sprite with another:

```
[playerSprite setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"playerWithShield.png"]];
```

Comment: Knnot thankx a lot i will try ur solution.but i have a confusion abt that.my player is not in still mode it is in moving mode and i dnt want to disturb its moving speed also

Comment: The code I suggested will only change the appearance of your sprite (with a new image) without affecting anything else. If the sprite was originally moving in a certain manner, it will continue to do so, no worries.

Comment: thanks a lot for your kind help.after a 5 seconds i want to get its orignal sprite image back after that time of interval.

Comment: You are welcome. At the point where you player gets the shield, you can schedule a function that resets its image back to the original one 5 seconds later. CODE: [self schedule:@selector(resetImage:) interval:5]. In the resetImage function, switch back the image using the same call as given in my answer, and unschedule this function so that you don't keep calling it every 5 seconds.

Comment: really thankx from heart.plz keep in touch i am new in game development and my final year proj is game so i need your kind help